# Include database in Service Fabric Reliable Services transaction

Tags: transactions, azure-service-fabric

Service Fabric has Reliable Services such as Reliable Collections and Reliable Queues. It has a Reliable State Manager that can start a transaction to atomically move things between a queue and a collection, etc.

Is it possible to include a database in this transaction, like Azure SQL Database or Azure Cosmos DB?